# getting maximum value for first element in list of lists in PySpark column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark column with values of list of lists like this

```
row 1: [['01', '100.0'], ['01', '400.0'], [None, '0.0'], ['06', '0.0'], ['01', '300'], [None, '0.0'], ['06', '200.0']]
row 2: [[None, '200.0'], ['06', '300.0'], ['01', '500'], ['06', '100.0'], ['01', '200'], ['07', '50.0']]
```

I need to compare elements with same first element in the list of lists and filter out the arrays with the maximum second element for each pair. While the array may have different codes for the first element, I want to filter out array elements containing '01' , '06' or '07' and add two columns to my dataframe.

So the result for a sample row above would look like this:

```
[['01', '400.0'], ['06', '200.0'], ['07':'0']
[['01', '500.0'], ['06', '300.0'], ['07':'50']
```

what's the most efficient way to do this?

[image]

Comment: can you post the code what you tried so far ?

Comment: can i assume that list of columns to add max_01, max_06, max_07 will be provided or do i have to ascertain that from the list of lists?

Comment: we can do a withColumn for the three codes 01, 06 and 07.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("Max_01",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(arr,x-> exists(x,y->y='01'))"""))!=0,
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(arr, x-> exists(x,y-> y='01')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .withColumn("Max_06",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(arr,x-> exists(x,y->y='06'))"""))!=0,
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(arr, x-> exists(x,y-> y='06')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .withColumn("Max_07",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(arr,x-> exists(x,y->y='07'))"""))!=0,
       F.expr("""array_max(transform(filter(arr, x-> exists(x,y-> y='07')),z-> float(z[1])))"""))\
             .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
   .show(truncate=False)

#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
#|arr                                                                              |Max_01|Max_06|Max_07|
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
#|[[01, 100.0], [01, 400.0], [, 0.0], [06, 0.0], [01, 400.0], [, 0.0], [06, 200.0]]|400.0 |200.0 |0.0   |
#|[[, 200.0], [06, 300.0], [01, 500], [06, 100.0], [01, 200], [07, 50.0]]          |500.0 |300.0 |50.0  |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this solves the problem I mentioned in the comment from the solution you provided to the other question.